# Multiple updatable partial views in one view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm working on my first ASP.NET MVC 4 (C#) application. I made an application that connects to a MongoDB database. I have made one page with an input form, one page with a list that displays the data and I have made one page with an edit/update form to edit the saved data.

This all works just fine, but I want to make the application more user friendly. Instead of switching between pages, I want to display the input form and the saved data on one page. And I want to update the saved data when new data has been inserted. And when I want to edit/update the saved data, the input form must be switched with the edit/update form.

I have read about `partial pages` and the `master page` (_Layout). And I have read that I can update the `partial pages` with javascript / jQuery.

Because I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, I want to know if this is the right and best way to achieve my goal, or is there a better way. Also, it would be nice to have some tips on what is important.

Comment: Yep, using AJAX in jQuery to call your controller methods to perform saves etc will improve the user experience. In terms of making the implementation a lot nicer consider using a client side framework such as AngularJS and Knockout so that you have a client side version of your model that is being updated dynamically. Updating hidden fields in jQuery can get very messy pretty quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your information! I will look into AngularJS and Knockout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC you have views, partial views, and layouts. All of these are "views" and, for the most part, the distinction lies only in how you use them.

A partial view is just a view that's rendered without a layout, which can be done by 1) returning `PartialView` from an action or 2) using the `Html.Partial` Razor helper in a view.

A layout is just a view that's referenced as the layout for another view. This can be achieved by either 1) manually specifying the layout in the view via `Layout = "~/Views/SomeLayout.cshtml";` or 2) by utilizing a `_ViewStart.cshtml` file. The only thing that makes a layout really different than any other view is that it will have a call to `@RenderBody()`, which indicates where the rendered result of whatever view references it should be placed.

That's a very brief primer to views in ASP.NET MVC. When it comes to utilizing something like AJAX to replace a portion of the page it's important to realize that at this point in the page life-cycle, there's no such thing as partials views, layouts, etc. All you have is HTML that the browser has received from the server and used to construct an internal representation of the webpage called the "DOM" or Document Object Model. You can't just replace a "partial view" on the page; you must replace a portion of the DOM. It may sound like semantics, but it's an important distinction, because the client, in this case a web browser, has no concept of what portions of the document were or were not rendered via partial views on the server-side, nor does it care.

However, the *source* of your replacement can be a partial view, at least in the sense that you can use a partial view to generate a result that can be sent to the client as a response. The action method that responds to your AJAX request can return `PartialView("_SomePartialView")` and that view will be render, with any data passed to it, without a layout, and sent to the client as a response. At this point, though, it's just HTML, and again, it makes no difference how that HTML was generated. The callback for your AJAX request will receive this HTML and must then do something with it. Unlike a typical browser request, the browser will not do anything with this response automatically (i.e. render a web page from it). It is your responsibility to select a portion of the DOM you want to replace and insert this HTML response into that DOM.

Comment: Thank you for this extensive answer!